# How to rearrange a ratio of Gamma functions to code it

Tags: matlab, gamma-distribution, chi-squared-distribution

I have to evaluate the following ratio:

$\frac{\Gamma(\frac{x}{2} - \frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{x}{2})}$

I am coding in MATLAB and I have this equation inside a loop. $x$ takes values between 2 and 400. MATLAB cannot compute the gamma function since the number is soo big. How can I rewrite this equation so that  I can compute the ratio?

Comment: Take advantage of Stirling’s approximation. Or if you’re stepping through values ascending-sequentially you can use the fact that the ratio changes by a simple factor.

Comment: no the values are random, they are not ascending sequentially

Comment: Sounds good. Use the approximation then.

Comment: It is not very familiar to me, could you expand please

Comment: https://letmegooglethat.com/?q=stirling%E2%80%99s+approximation

Comment: Use the log-gamma function instead. For instance, in R, `lgamma(x)` can be called for `x` up to 10³⁰⁵.

Comment: For examples of @Xi'an's suggestion in practice, see [this site search for `lgamma` and over/under flow](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=lgamma+*flow+score%3A2).